# Make a circular Voronoi diagram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, voronoi

I have a data frame that looks like this and I want to create a circular voronoi diagram with it

```r
df <- data.frame(country = c("Ukraine", "Russia", "Argentina", "China", "Romania", "Other"),
                 prod = c(11.0, 10.6, 3.1, 2.4, 2.1, 15.3))

df
#>     country prod
#> 1   Ukraine 11.0
#> 2    Russia 10.6
#> 3 Argentina  3.1
#> 4     China  2.4
#> 5   Romania  2.1
#> 6     Other 15.3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library("ggvoronoi")

df <- data.frame(country = c("Ukraine", "Russia", "Argentina", "China", "Romania", "Other"),
                 prod = c(11.0, 10.6, 3.1, 2.4, 2.1, 15.3))

ggplot(df, aes(country, prod)) +
  geom_voronoi(aes(fill=prod)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Does anyone have an idea of how I could make it circular?
I have found this github link but its missing the data that I need to convert polygons to a circular voronoi
https://github.com/nrennie/30DayChartChallenge/blob/main/2022/scripts/04_flora.R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linked picture is a Voronoi treemap. There is an R package called `voronoiTreemap` you can use to create one yourself:

```r
library(voronoiTreemap)

vor <- data.frame(h1 = 'World', 
                  h2 = c('Europe', 'Europe', 'Americas', 'Asia',
                         'Europe', 'Other'),
                  h3 = df$country,
                  color = hcl.colors(nrow(df), palette = 'TealRose'),
                  weight = df$prod,
                  codes = df$country)

vt <- vt_input_from_df(vor)

vt_d3(vt_export_json(vt))
```

[image]